# How to draw 2 dimensional cumulative distribution function from data?

Tags: matplotlib, distribution, cdf

I have a 2-d dataset [[2010, 2017, 1937, ...,],[1,1,3,....,]], I want to draw the cumulative distribution function from the data.

Now I can draw the PDF with plt.hist2d(), but how can I draw the CDF?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.hist2d` returns a matrix of histogram values, the bin boundaries in the x and in the y direction, and a mesh object. You could sum up the histogram values in both directions and plot these.

`np.histogram2d` can replace `plt.hist2d`, returning the same values except the mesh object.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 200
x = np.random.randint(1900, 2020, N)
y = np.random.randint(1, 10, N)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))
hist_vals, xbins, ybins, mesh = ax1.hist2d(x, y)
ax2.pcolormesh(xbins, ybins, hist_vals.cumsum(axis=0).cumsum(axis=1))
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: This is wrong. CDF is an integral, you have to multiply your right plot by dx and dy